# How to get correct time zone offset with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, timezone, timezone-offset, timestamp-with-timezone

I am trying to get the correct time zone offset in my result but it looks to only give me the offset in accordance with the Postgres time zone (UTC +00).

```
SELECT ('2023-01-01 12:00:00'::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'CEST')::timestamptz;
> 2023-01-01 14:00:00+00
```

What I would like to get is `2023-01-01 14:00:00+02` which would be the correct offset from UTC to CEST.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name for me `SELECT '2023-01-01 12:00:00'::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'CEST'` without the casting returns `2023-01-01 14:00:00` with the casting it returns `2023-01-01 14:00:00+00`

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get that output is to set the `timezone` parameter to `CEST` (or something equivalent). PostgreSQL will *always* display a time zone offset that corresponds to the current setting of `timezone`.

Your query answers the question: if a wall clock in CEST shows 12:00:00, what is the actual time (displayed in my time zone)?